# 2009 C300 not starting

Tags: starting, mercedes-benz, c300

OK, my car is not starting as of yesterday. Today I installed new battery (was 6 years old) hopping that this will fix it, clean-up all connection with wire brush. This is what happens I will unlock car with remote key fob, put key in ignition and I can hear steering lock unlock column, all dash lights will come on, all text and numbers are clearly visible but when I turn key to turn starter over nothing will happen no crank, no click. I tried to crank starter on solenoid connection and starter works fine, but even if I leave ignition switch on and crank starter car will not start, any idea what to do?